# How to do multi string replace in a multiline text file that has almost a million lines using PowerShell?

Tags: regex, powershell

I have a few log files ( mosquitto broker logs) that have the following format

```
1652855102: New connection from xx.xx.xx.xx on port xxxx.
1652855102: Socket error on client <unknown>, disconnecting.
1652855102: Received PUBLISH from 16838547124974742985 (d0, q1, r0, m235, 's/uc/mpd/16838547124974742985', ... (30 bytes))
1652855102: Sending PUBACK to 16838547124974742985 (m235, rc0)
1652855102: Sending PUBLISH to mqtt_7811e829.e2e5e8 (d0, q1, r0, m42277, 's/uc/mpd/16838547124974742985', ... (30 bytes))
1652855102: Sending PUBLISH to dad3d73-013c-4274-a782-cdd6f2ebbc77 (d0, q0, r0, m0, 's/uc/mpd/16838547124974742985', ... (30 bytes))
1652855102: Received PUBACK from mqtt_7811e829.e2e5e8 (Mid: 42277, RC:0)
1652855103: Received DISCONNECT from 16838547082470259932
1652855103: Client 16838547082470259932 disconnected.
```

The format is as follows:
`UTC time in seconds since epoch|:| Message body`

I want to transform the log file into:

```
1652855102|New connection from xx.xx.xx.xx on port xxxx.
1652855102|Socket error on client <unknown>, disconnecting.
1652855102|Received PUBLISH from 16838547124974742985 (d0, q1, r0, m235, 's/uc/mpd/16838547124974742985', ... (30 bytes))
1652855102|Sending PUBACK to 16838547124974742985 (m235, rc0)
```

I understand that there are 3 groups here to be captured 
`Group 1` - first 10 digits
`Group 2` - a colon and a space
`Group 3` - everything after the space is message

```
$RegEx = '(?ms)^([\d]{10})(:\s)(.+)'
(Get-Content -Raw ..\sample-mosquitto.log) -Replace $RegEx, '$1|$3'
```

My script only replaces the first line and doesn't work for the rest of the lines.

Is there any way to run the capture and replace for all lines without actually doing a `for-each` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Your only problem is the use of inline regex option `s`**, i.e. the `SingleLine`  option that makes metacharacter `.` match *any* character, *including newlines*; in effect, this causes your regex to match the *entire string, across all lines*; *without* this option, `.` matches any character *other than a newline*, which is what you're looking for here.

Also note that character class `\s` matches *any whitespace* character, and therefore also newlines; while that isn't a problem in your case, it is better to simply match a   (space) verbatim, if you know that only a space can occur in that position.

Finally, note that it is sufficient to use *one* capture group, because you needn't capture the separator string, given that you're replacing it with a fixed character, and you need not capture the remainder of the string, given that it should remain unchanged.

Therefore (note that inline option `m` (`Multiline`) is still needed to make `^` match the start of *each line*):

```bash
(Get-Content -Raw ..\sample-mosquitto.log) -replace '(?m)^(\d{10}): ', '$1|'
```

Re **performance**:

Assuming the file fits into memory as a whole (which is typically true even for large text files), **use of the `-Raw` switch to read the file into a single, multi-line string is indeed the fastest way to process the file**; by contrast, using [`Get-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content) *without* `-Raw` would result in *line-by-line* streaming, which is not only inherently slower, but slowed down by each line getting decorated with metadata - see [GitHub issue #7537](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/7537) for a discussion about a potential future opt-out.

However - again assuming that the file fits into memory as a whole - there *is* a way to **speed up `Get-Content`'s line-by-line processing**, namely **via `-ReadCount 0`**, which causes *all* lines to be emitted as a *single array* (which requires only a *single* output object, which only *as a whole* is decorated with metadata):

```bash
# Slower than -Raw, but reasonably fast line-by-line processing,
# thanks to -ReadCount 0
(Get-Content -ReadCount 0 ..\sample-mosquitto.log) -replace '^(\d{10}): ', '$1|'
```

Comment: Thanks @mklement0
This worked like a charm. I can't believe I was using the single line option.
Also yea makes sense that I need only 1 capture group.

The files fit in memory just fine and each replace took under 1s each and when used intandem with PowerShell's -Parallel option with ForEach-Object, 8 large files were replaced in 2.5s. The code I am using now is

```
Get-ChildItem -Name *.log* | ForEach-Object -Parallel {
    $RegEx = '(?m)^([\d]{10}): ';
    (Get-Content -Raw $_) -Replace $RegEx, '$1|' | Out-File -Path "replaced\replaced.$($_)"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using

```
$RegEx = '^(\d{10}):\s+(.+)'
(Get-Content ..\sample-mosquitto.log) -Replace $RegEx, '$1|$2'
```

That is, remove `-Raw` as you want to operate on a line by line basis, and only capture the data that you need to keep (`:\s+` does not need keeping, and neither capturing). See the updated replacement string with `$1|$2`.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/IizmrX/2).

If loading the whole file into memory is not a problem, you can go on using the `-Raw` option and the multiline matching regex:

```
$RegEx = '(?m)^(\d{10}):\s+(.+)'
(Get-Content ..\sample-mosquitto.log -Raw) -Replace $RegEx, '$1|$2'
```

Note the removed `s` flag that made `.` match line feed chars (LF).

Also, note that in case you do not care if there are any chars on the line after `:` and a whitespace, i.e. if you need to replace `:` after ten digits with a `|`, you can use

```
$RegEx = '(?m)(?<=^\d{10}):\s+'
(Get-Content ..\sample-mosquitto.log -Raw) -Replace $RegEx, '|'
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/IizmrX/3).

And finally: if you do not need to remove line break chars after `:`, replace `\s` with either `[^\S\r\n]`, or `[\s-[\r\n]]` or `[\p{Zs}\t]`:

```
$RegEx = '(?m)(?<=^\d{10}):[\p{Zs}\t]+'
```

that will only match horizontal whitespace chars.

Comment: While that is conceptually simpler (also note that there's no need for the second capture group either), note that `Get-Content`'s default line-by-line streaming is very slow, potentially prohibitively so with a near 1-million lines file, as stipulated in the question.

Comment: @mklement0 The second group is necessary to make sure there is more that just a single whitespace after `:`. Probably, the pattern must be `'^(\d{10}):\s+(\S.*)'` to work even better.

Comment: True, if you want to exclude lines that _end_ in a separator, you need a capture group. While that is technically true of the OP's own attempt,
the sample data suggests that characters always follow the separator, in which case no extra capture group is needed.
And if there _are_ lines that end in a separator, not using an extra capture group replaces the separator with verbatim `|` there too, which is arguably better than leaving the lines unmodified.
Anyway, the OP / future readers can pick what works better for them (leaving the `Get-Content` performance problem aside).

Comment: @Wiktor, thanks for your help! Your implmentation works, however its slower than using Get-Content -Raw and using multiline regex option. 
8 files took me 6min to replace the strings while using Get-Content without the Raw option - i.e line by line streaming and replace

Where as while using -Raw option and using multiline regex replace option 8 files took under 3s

Thank you and mklement0 both! I can get on with parsing my logs and do my job!

Comment: @miniGweek Great, I added some more alternatives.